# dual iterator in one python object

Tags: python, iterator

In python, I am trying to write a class that support two different kind of iterator. Roughly speaking, this object contains a matrix of data and I want to have two different kind of iterator to support row iteration and column iteration.

Answer (score 5):

`dict` has several iterator-producing methods -- `iterkeys`, `itervalues`, `iteritems` -- and so should your class. If there's one "most natural" way of iterating, you should also alias it to `__iter__` for convenience and readability (that's probably going to be `iterrows`; of course there is always going to be some doubt, as there was with `dict` when we designed its iteration behavior, but a reasonable pick is better than none).

For example, suppose your matrix is square, held flattened up into a row-major list `self.data`, with a side of `self.n`. Then:

```
def iterrows(self):
  start = 0
  n = self.n
  data = self.data
  while start < n*n:
    stop = start + n
    yield data[start:stop]
    start = stop

def itercols(self):
  start = 0
  n = self.n
  data = self.data
  while start < n:
    yield data[start::n]
    start += 1

__iter__ = iterrows
```

Comment: Why not (self.data[start : start + self.n] for start in xrange(0, self.n*self.n, self.n)) for your implementation of iterrows?

Comment: I just prefer hoisting the self.whatever lookups out of the loop when convenient -- they're not supposed to change during iteration anyway, but Python doesn't do that optimization. But there's surely more than one way to iterate efficiently, I just like the symmetry between the two cases here!

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self._rows = rows

    def columns(self):
        return zip(*self._rows)

    def rows(self):
        return self._rows

# Create a Matrix by providing rows.
m = Matrix([[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]])

# Iterate in row-major order.
for row in m.rows():
    for value in row:
        print value

# Iterate in column-major order.
for column in m.columns():
    for value in column:
        print value
```

You can use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` if you want to create each column on demand.

You can also move the iteration of the actual values into the class. I wasn't sure if you wanted to iterate over rows/columns (as shown) or the values *in* the rows/columns.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so make two separate methods where each is a generator.

```
class Matrix(object):
    def iter_rows(self):
        for row in self.rows:
            yield row

    def iter_columns(self):
        for column in self.columns:
            yield column
```

Your `__iter__` could iterate over one or the other by default, though I'd recommend having no `__iter__` at all.

Comment: The ability to write `for row in matrix` is essential part of Python syntax therefore it is better to define __iter__ somehow than having no __iter__ at all.